# Using AutoMapper to copy data from SuperClass to SubClass

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to transfer all values from SuperClass to Subclass in the Constructor.
My Idea is I am going to pass the superclass object in the constructor and it will automatically populate the values to the current object (subclass).

The error I am getting at the line 'this = a' is :

```
Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only
```

My View Model Class

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel : Models.AssetItem
    {
        public ItemDetailViewModel()
        {
        }
        public ItemDetailViewModel(Models.AssetItem model)
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Models.AssetItem, ItemDetailViewModel>());

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var a = mapper.Map<ItemDetailViewModel>(model);

            this = a;
        }

        // Other Properties & Methods for View Models

    }
```

How can I copy the data from super class to sub class?

Is there a better way to copy the properties (with the same name) from one object to another object?

Comment: So you're trying to override SubClass with SuperClass *within* SubClass itself? Doesn't seem logical. You would map one to the other from the outside.

Comment: It seems that yes, I am.  So, should I move that code to the SuperClass?  For Eg. AssetItem.ConvertToItemDetailViewModel() which returns ViewModel

Answer (score 1):

What I believe you want is to modify the super (parent) class so that it has a copy constructor.  The [Article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms173116.aspx) explains this a bit, and a second article about calling the base-class methods at construction time also has a [good example for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx#Example), but to YOUR example here, what you want is something "like" below:

```
// Used a shortened version of the name for the example here
public class AssetItem
{
    public AssetItem(AssetItem other)
    {
        // COPY the contents of other to your "this" instance one element at a time.
        // Don't try assigning over "this"
    }
}

public class ItemDetailViewModel : Models.AssetItem
{
    public ItemDetailViewModel()
    {
    }

    public ItemDetailViewModel(Models.AssetItem model)
        : base(model)
    {
        // Your superclass is "set up" already by now
    }

        // Other Properties & Methods for View Models

}
```

Read through the two examples, and see if that helps.  If you don't have control of the superclass, then it's harder.  It may already have a copy constructor though, you just need to look for it.